# Chrome won't download/Internet Explorer opens on own

Tags: google-chrome, internet, windows-explorer, download

All of a sudden my Chrome browser won't download the complete file of whatever it is I'm trying to get.  What I get says either that it is a incomplete file (and they are much smaller than the one I was going for) or it isn't a proper Win32 file when I know that they should be.  At the same time this started happening I no longer could open a hyper link in Outlook 2010 and for some reason Internet Explorer would open itself up at some random add.  I've tried with Uninstaller Pro and System Mechanic 12.5 to fix this but neither  program seem able to find the problem.   Plus a system restore didn't work.  Can anyone help?

Comment: Run `sfc /scanow` and `Dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth`( if you are using windows 8 )your windows installation sounds corrupt